# How do I write this regex to replace a string in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

If the string begins with `^abc`,don't modify it.otherwise append `abc` to the beginning of it.

I know it can be done by **2** steps:`m//` and `s//`,but I want to do it in a single `s/../` in perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s/^(?!\^abc)/abc/
```

does the trick, although

```
$_ = 'abc'.$_ if !/^\^abc/;
```

might be clearer.

---

```
>perl -E"$_=$ARGV[0]; s/^(?!\^abc)/abc/; say;" "^abcdef"
^abcdef

>perl -E"$_=$ARGV[0]; s/^(?!\^abc)/abc/; say;" "defghi"
abcdefghi

>perl -E"$_=$ARGV[0]; $_ = 'abc'.$_ if !/^\^abc/; say;" "^abcdef"
^abcdef

>perl -E"$_=$ARGV[0]; $_ = 'abc'.$_ if !/^\^abc/; say;" "defghi"
abcdefghi
```

Comment: @Learning, `(?!PAT)` matches if what follows doesn't match `PAT`. [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Comment: @ikegami,just tried,seems not working. BTW,does `(?!PAT)` do capture?

Comment: @Learning, It works fine. Added tests to post. // No, `(?!PAT)` doesn't capture, but you can use captures in it.

Comment: @ikegami,seems it doesn't work when the pattern is `\^## Copyright (C) 19XX by Yours\n`,is the `\^` necessary here?

Comment: @Learning, Probably cause you want `...\(C\)...`

Comment: @Learning, `\^` is necessary if the string to match starts with `^`. It's wrong if the string to match doesn't start with `^`.